# Spring AOP, applying protected/private advice

Tags: java, spring-aop

I've been playing around with Spring's aop:config XML configuration. When I made the advice method a protected/private method, I was expecting to get a run time exception. However the advice method was correctly executed. Does it mean that Spring is modifying the advice method access permission, or is something else happening here? To clarify:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void foo() {} // advised method
}

public class Bar
{
    private void bar() {} // advice method, this e.g. will be applied as before-advice to foo() above
}
```

Both Foo and Bar classes are in different packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When processing an advice, Spring process each annotated class through reflection, and does not call the methods of your class directly from outside, so the visibility privileges of your advices are not relevant.

Unluckily, there is no precise documentation that explain how Spring works so deeply, you will have to help yourself with digging in the source code. This makes sense as the goal of the documentation of an open-source project is not to explain the internals, but rather how to make usage of the features that the project provide.

If you really want to look inside the documentation, http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension explains you that AOP is applied through BeanFactoryPostProcessors,  and then you might want to look at the javadoc:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/aop/framework/package-tree.html

Comment: could you pl. link to any relevant doc if possible?